# What sort of transform would give me the desired resultant image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, transformation, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform

It feels simple really. I have an UIImageView:

[image: start]

and I want to apply an affine transform to get this image:

[image: end]

However, the particular transform in question eludes me. Rotating by 180° gets me this:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
// similarly, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, -1);
```

[image: rotate]

which is oviously quite far off. Translation is also problematic:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
```

[image: translate]

Reflecting over the line `y = x` and then rotating 180° gets me this:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformMake(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(M_PI);
```

[image: reflect-rotate]

which is closer, but still not there. Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or is this really complicated? Does anyone know what sort of transform I'm looking for here?

**Edit:**

Twitter feedback is suggesting that affine transforms aren't the way to go. At the end of the day, I simply want the resultant image, so any suggested routes to success are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to move a sprite, whether you realize it or not. No transformation can move the star and keep the background. Your options are to:
- make a large background and clip it at the end, so that translation works
- make a sprite image on top of a separate background image. If you're using iOS7, you may want to use the Sprite Kit.